# Converting a for-loop with continue statement to while-loop

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, continue

I am working on an exercise where a small piece of code based on a for-loop is converted to preform the same operation with a while loop. The conversion is wrong by purpose, and looks like this:

```
int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) continue;
        sum += i;   
    }
System.out.println(sum); // prints 3
```

This is converted into:

```
int i = 0, sum = 0;

        while (i < 4) {
            if (i % 3 == 0) continue;
            sum += i;   
            i++;    
        }
System.out.println(sum); // will not print
```

In the exercise, I am asked to explain why the conversion is wrong and then fix it. My thoughts are:

1. With the initial value of **i = 0**, this will trigger **continue** instantly after entering the will loop, since **(0 % 3 == 0)** will make the **if-statement** true. As long as the initial value is 0, this will execute the loop, for so to skip it an endless amount of times. I tried changing the initial value of **i = 1**, but noe sum is printed. Then I tried to increment **i** before executing the **if-statement**, and the program now prints the sum 7. The question here is; why won't the program print if i incremented after the if statement, even if the initial value of i = 1 suggests (in my head) that program should run properly?
2. I made a table for each program to compare the summing.

The **for-loop** version:

i = 0, sum += i not preformed (continue), i++

i = 1, sum = 1, i++

i = 2, sum = 3, i++

i = 3, sum += i not preformed (continue), i++

i = 4, i < 4 false, loop stopped

The **while-loop** version:

i = 0, i++, sum = 1

i = 1, i++, sum = 3

i = 2, i++, sum += i not preformed (continue)

i = 3, i++, sum = 7

i = 4, i < 4 false, loop stopped

In the **while-loop**, sum += i is preformed once more than in the **for-loop**. Is this the right way to convert the **for-loop** into a **while-loop**?

```
int i = 0, sum = 0;

        while (i < 3) {
            i++;
            if (i % 3 == 0) continue;
            sum += i;           
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: for 1. `3 % 3` is zero

Comment: Strictly speaking there is another difference: `i` is now visible from the rest of the block. An equivalent of a `for(int i=0;....) {}` construct is `{ int i = 0; while (...) {} }` (note the extra pair of braces enclosing both the variable declaration and the loop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **for-loop** given by the question if converted to plain **English**, it means **sum up** from **0 to 3** and exclude **all multiples of 3**. (0+1+2=3)

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) continue;
        sum += i;   
    }
```

So now, we ask ourselves, how do we sum up 0 to x and exclude all multiples of 3 using a **while-loop**. We will do this without looking at the original **for-loop**. (*Sometimes it is easier to do it this way since we already know the intention of the for-loop*)

**To sum up a number from 0 to 3:**

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 4){
    sum += i;
    i++;
}
```

**To sum a number from 0 to 3, excluding multiples of 3:**

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 4){
    if(i % 3 != 0)
        sum += i;
    i++;
}
```

**To sum a number from 0 to 3, excluding multiples of 3 (using continue):**

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 4){
    if(i % 3 == 0){
        i++;       //Remember to increase i before continue
        continue;
    }
    else
        sum += i;
    i++;
}
```

Since after the `continue`, all statements below it will be skipped, you have to remember to do an increment `i++` before calling `continue`. There will be another `i++` since you branch out into 2 conditions now.

Answer (score 5):

Your `1` is focussing on it being the initial value, but that's not the point. The point is that `i` is never incremented when `i % 3 == 0` is true, not that `0` is the initial value. So the `while` loop loops forever.

Your `2` doesn't make any sense: The `while` version will loop forever, never summing anything.

> Is this the right way to convert the for-loop into a while-loop?

No, you're incrementing `i` at the wrong time.

Think bout how a `for` loop works:

1. *Initialization* - First it sets the variables to the values in the first expression.
2. *Test* - Then it tests the values using the second expression.
3. *Execute* - If the value is true, it executes the loop body.
4. *Increment* - When the loop body is complete, it executes the third (increment) expression. Note that this is **after** the loop body.

Make your `while` loop do what the `for` loop is doing. (I'm intentionally *not* doing that for you; this is a learning exercise. I'll note that the best way to convert that `for` loop will not use `continue`, however. "Best," of course, is subjective.)

Answer (score 5):

> In the exercise, I am asked to explain why the conversion is wrong and then fix it

The conversion is wrong simply because when you will reach a `i` value that modulo 3 equals 0 (the first iteration in that case), you will skip to the next iteration and re-validate. However, since you skipped directly without incrementing `i` , you will re-validate the same condition and re-validate *ad-infinitum*.

You could fix it easily by getting rid of the `continue` and negating the condition :

```
while (i < 4) {
    if (i % 3 != 0)
        sum += i;

    i++;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the while loop logic, increment of variable i is conditional where as for for-loop it is unconditional. To make the increment logic uniform, you should increment in both cases.

I think the proper converting would be -

```
int i = 0, sum = 0;

while (i < 4) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {i++;continue;}
    sum += i;   
    i++;   
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: This could be simplified, you're incrementing in and outside the `if` why not always increment ? The `continue` simply have nothing to do here.

Comment: Hay @Jean-FrançoisSavard, yes we can only thing that would break the  conversion uniformity

Answer (score 0):

Normally the increment would be on the last line of a while loop.  However, in this "disaster waiting to happen" code, there is a condition to skip to the end of the while block without incrementing i.  If you are relying on i to increment, make sure it is always executed on any iteration.  And also, at the end, because you want it to iterate the first time.

```
    while (i < 4) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
          // skip!
        } else {
          sum += i;   
        }
        i++;    
    }
```